# Drupal: Getting user name on user account page without breaking performance

Tags: performance, drupal, caching

I have multiple blocks shown on the user profile page, user/uid

On each of them, I need to print the user name.

I've been doing a `$user = user_load(arg(1)); print $user->name;` on each block. Since there is no caching, as you can image the performance is HORRIBLE.

Is there either a way to get the user name more efficiently or to cache user_load.

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, it's a good practice to never use the $user variable name for anything other than the current user in Drupal. Because the global $user is the current user, changing that variable actually logs someone in as another user. It's pretty easy to forget you've used the name $user somewhere, go back later and add "global $user", and open a huge security hole in your site. Using $account instead of $user is an easy way to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) which is the proper way to retrieve an *object* (user, node, etc.) loaded from the URL of a properly declared page. It will return the user object that has already been loaded using the uid found at `arg(1)` for a *menu item* which use `%user` in its path (ie. `$items['user/%user']`, $`items['user/%user/view']`, etc. in [`user_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_menu/7).

```
$account = menu_get_object('user');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add an intermediate function to provide the static caching yourself:

```
/**
 * Proxy for user_load(), providing static caching
 * NOTE: Only works for the common use of user_load($uid) - will NOT load by name or email
 *
 * @param int $uid - The uid of the user to load
 * @param bool $reset - Wether to reset the static cache for the given uid, defaults to FALSE
 * @return stdClass - A fully-loaded $user object upon successful user load or FALSE if user cannot be loaded.
 */
function yourModule_user_load_cached($uid, $reset = FALSE) {
  static $users = array();

  // Do we need to (re)load the user?    
  if (!isset($users[$uid]) || $reset) {
    $users[$uid] = user_load($uid);
  }

  return $users[$uid];
}
```

Comment: menu_get_object('user') will avoid doing any unnecessary user_load().

Answer (score 0):

The user is a global.

function myfunction() {
  global $user;
}